# IOS: How to draw and calculate position of the custom callout arrow in IOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to implement an application which has a map and on that map there are several pins. Also I am implementing a custom `callout` view for the map annotations by sub classing the `MKAnnotationView` class.

Every thing is working fine but I am unable to draw the `callout` arrow and cannot calculate the exact position of the callout arrow so that it shows right on top of the annotation pin.

Currently I am just adding my custom callout view as a subview of MKAnnotationView and altering its frame. But cannot draw and position the callout arrow on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [SMCalloutView project](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview) which has built out this functionality.